# Kibana Maps: Results limited to first 10000 documents

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have created an index in ES with around 500K documents. When I visualize this index in Kibana Elastic Map, a message pop-up notifying "Results limited to first 10000 documents".
I increased the value of the "index.max_result_window" setting, but it does not work.

The version on my ES is 7.4.2

Can anyone guide me on how to increase this limitation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after reading this, I realise that this is a known issue and had been fixed since version 7.6.

[[Maps] Consider options beyond aggregations for obtaining es search results docs over the 10k limit #49971](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/49971)

update: with #53500, starting 7.6, users can now set the max_result_window setting on the index to move beyond the 10k document and agg limit.